# using tortoise svn in small office

Tags: svn, networking, tortoisesvn

We have a small software house in which we have lets say three computers, we work in PHP mostly. We are trying to adopt tortoise svn so that we can sync our code. All computers are connected in local network via WiFi (tplink router)

### **Problem** :

- I install tortoise svn in D drive and make a repository in svn_repo
  folder and make a copy named svn_repowc.
- I know how to commit and    how to add and update. but I don't know
  how to connect my b computer    with a computer?
- do I use URL to connect them or I use svnserve ??
- can i use file url to connect them or svn url ????
- if I use svn serve    do I edit the password file in config folder?

Answer (score 2):

You should install subversion server on one PC. Then connect each PC with tortoise svn as client.

I would use a full fledged server like [Apache subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).

Comment: You must know what you prefer, I use Apache subversion and didn't try Visualsvn. If you use Visual Studio, then use VisualSvn, as one is made for the other. If you prefer open source, go for Apache subversion.